# Regular expression for a comma-separated word in Python

Tags: python

How can I get all the words which are comma separated before a particular word in Python using a regular expression?

Example:

```
s=" A,B particular_word is the C,D particular_word"
```

Output for particular_word  A B C D

Comment: 'particular_word' is in both cases identical? Is it always the same word? Have you had a look into regex? Is regex your problem or Python, or both?

Comment: Can you specify/explain what you've tried? Would help us jump start.

Comment: yes particular_word is identical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following regex to find the stuff you're looking for:

```
import re
s = " A,B particular_word is the C,D particular_word"
word_finder = r'(?:([^\W]+),([^\W]+))\Wparticular_word'
matches = re.findall(word_finder, s)
```

This will return a list of tuples with the words inside them. Note that this work by NOT matching word's (`\W`).

You can also flatten the list as follows:

```
words = [w for word_tuple in matches for w in word_tuple]
```